# C# DateTime Parsing Problem

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, datetimepicker

My current code looks like this:

```
        DateTime dateBegin = DateTime.ParseExact(begin, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
        DateTime dateEnd = DateTime.ParseExact(end, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
```

But it throws an exception whenever the date in "end" is different. I get the dates from a DateTimePicker control, thus the date may look like "1/12/2010" and then it'll throw the exception. How do I avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this in ASP.NET / WinForms / WPF?

Answer (score 12):

Is this winforms? just use [`.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) on the picker and you'll get the right `DateTime` - no need to parse.

Ultimately, "1/12/2010" **isn't** "MM/dd/yyyy"; you could also try ""M/d/yyyy" as a fallback?

```
string s = "1/12/2010";
string[] formats = { "MM/dd/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy" };
DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use DateTimePicker.Value?

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting the value from a DateTimePicker, why not use tha Value of that control which is already a DateTime?  I'm not sure why you're trying to parse the string...

Answer (score 0):

If you provided the stack/exception information ti may be easier to help but I would expect it is throwing as the ParseExact is failing probably because it doesn't fit the format you are trying to narrow it too

Answer (score 0):

how about this ?

```
string begin = @"1/12/2010";
DateTime dateBegin = DateTime.ParseExact(begin, "M/dd/yyyy", null);
```

A good reference is

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: And, to avoid the same problem with the day, use "M/d/yyyy", or even "M/d/y"